# (Ventoy) After selecting Ubuntu in grub, I get a error that says I need to load the kernel

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

So, I set up a Ventoy Flash Drive with 3 ISOs on it:
Ubuntu
Arch
Windows 10
But when I boot ubuntu, I get a grub screen and after selecting ubuntu, I get the error:
`error: you need to load the kernel first`!
Windows 10 and Arch work fine.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is it? Did you check at the Ventoy web site, that it supports your version of Ubuntu? Did you check that the Ubuntu iso file was downloaded correctly (check with `sha256sum`)?

Comment: @sudodus It's Ubuntu 20.04 and I'm seeing the hash right now, I thought it's impossible to use hashes on windows

Comment: @sudodus Well, WinMD5Sum just hangs up but I am sure it's correct since I previously installed ubuntu using this iso

Comment: Maybe you can boot into Arch and run `sha256sum` on the Ubuntu iso file. If the sha256sum matches with the uploaded value, I think there is a problem with Ventoy (if not the Ubuntu iso file copy on the Ventoy USB pendrive). -- If you already installed with this iso file, please use the same tool/method that was successful.

Comment: @sudodus I tried to do so but I cannot mount the ventoy partition, It gives the error: `partition already mounted or mount point is busy`.

Comment: Did you try to reach the iso file via the already mounted partition? If still no luck, maybe we must accept that this Ubuntu iso file does not work with Ventoy. But there are many other tools to create USB boot drives. If I understand correctly, you already installed with this iso file, so please use the same tool/method that was successful.

Comment: @sudodus The only USB device I have is this one and the method previously used was complicated:
Use the main PC's SSD for it but I'll just give up now

Comment: I saw another answer saying to load the linux kernel manually on a another question, I'll just try that and post a answer if that was what I had to do

Comment: @sudodus I did not find a already mounted one

Comment: @sudodus Interestingly enough, this actually works in a VM.
My guess is that it's loading the windows kernel on the ssd instead of the linux kernel in the ventoy ISO and that is causing it to fail

Comment: @sudodus +I'm using VMWare Player with Plop to boot into the USB

Comment: You are using very special methods to boot into the USB. What computer is it? Please tell us the *brand name and model* of the computer itself and also of the CPU and of the graphics processor. Also, please tell us how much RAM there is.

Comment: My real PC or the VM?

Comment: My real pc is a Lenovo ThinkBook 14 IIL with 8 GB RAM and a Intel i3 10th generation CPU, My VM is a VMware VM with 2 GB RAM and idk anything else + I use Plop only for the VM, not my real PC

Comment: Thanks for sharing those details :-) My next questions/comments: Where do you use the Ventoy USB drive (in the real PC or in the VMware virtual machine or in both or should we say 'many' computers)? I don't see the reason why you should use Ventoy in a virtual machine, because it should work well to boot directly from the iso files in the host computer (seen as a virtual optical device (DVD disk)). But it can be meaningful to have a multiboot USB drive in order to boot many computers (to test, repair or install).

Comment: I use it in both, I use it in a VM only to test it.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, that Ventoy + Ubuntu 20.04 LTS will not work in any of the cases, neither in real computers nor in VMware? In that case I suggest that you **ask for help at a Ventoy web site, and if still no luck report it as a bug to the Ventoy developers**. -- I have a Lenovo workstation (my main computer) and two Lenovo laptops (one newer and one older), and all current Ubuntu versions work in them. The most straightforward method to make a USB boot drive is cloning from the iso file (and there are many cloning tools), but also extraction with Rufus works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, my problem solved itself.
While installing Ubuntu on a old laptop I found in my store room, I noticed that the installation works. Now it works on my main PC too!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Someone As stated in the answer, I didn't know how it happened.

Comment: OK. I understand the concern. However, your answer does not provide a solution to this question, does it? It should be an edit to the question.

Comment: Writing that as a self-answer seems fine imho. I closed the question now, as the issue went away on its own and can no longer be reproduced, so no answers could be verified or further information be given anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's might be UEFI boot issue.

Try to switch between legacy boot and UEFI boot in your BIOS settings.

[image: bios settings]

Comment: The mode isn't the problem. Ubuntu works in both (unless when the media is made with Rufus).

Comment: I already use UEFI. +@ChanganAuto I use Ventoy, So it's directly from the ISO and I flashed ventoy using Rufus because Ventoy2Disk wasn't working, like mentioned here: https://www.ventoy.net/en/doc_ventoy2disk.html